# C# FTP The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-4.5

This is my code
I have an FTP with many `zip` files. and each zip file has a `XML` with the same name.
I want to parse these xml files.

What i did is this:

1. get a list of all zip files in the FTP and save the names in this variable `directories`.
2. Now I want to open each zip file, which its name is in the `directories` list. I did this.

   ```
   foreach (string fileNameInFTP in directories)                   
   {
   }
   ```
3. Now to read the content of that zip file, I tried this:.

   ```
   string fileName =  FTPAddress + fileNameInFTP;
   using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
   using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
   {
         foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
         {
              using (var stream = entry.Open())
              {
                     // do whatever we want with stream
                     // ...
              }
         }
    }
   ```

I got this exception `The given path's format is not supported.` on this line:
`using (var file = File.OpenRead("ftp://" +FTPAddress +"/" + fileNameInFTP))` could u help  please

Comment: What does the final string/path look like? Perhaps there's an extra slash in there?

Comment: @Chris I will debug and tell u

Comment: Never mind, the issue is probably just that the `File.OpenRead` method doesn't support ftp. Try using `WebRequest` instead.

Comment: @Chris the result is `"ftp://172.28.4.7/Erb3PCustsExport-152848_20141225_000520_000.zip"` which is 100% correct file address

Comment: @StuartLC I already used the `FtpWebRequrest` to get the files names in the FTP server, should I use it again?

Comment: @StuartLC I wanna pass that xml file,which is inside the zip file, to the `XDocument.Load(`, so in that case, what should I do please?

Comment: Yes, you would need to again use FtpWebRequest to retrieve a file from a web site. Your error indicates that you aren't getting as far as unzipping the Zip archive, enumerating the files contained within, opening one of the files, and loading it into a Dom Parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something like this instead of trying to use File.OpenRead for remote FTP file download.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

using (var zip = new ZipArchive(responseStream , ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
   //Loops through each file in the zip that has the ".xml" extension 
   foreach (var entry in zip.Entries.Where(x=> (Path.GetExtension(x.Name) ?? "").ToLower() ==".xml"))
   {
        using (var stream = entry.Open())
        {
            //Load xml file and do whatever you like with it.
            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

Comment: I wanna pass the xml file, which locates inside the zip file, to the `XDocument.Load()`, could you edit your code please to add the xml to the `XDocument.Load(` please?

Comment: Edited the answer with XDocument.Load

Answer (score 2):

you can't use `File` IO to open FTP stream, here is a sample of how we can open FTP using `WebRequest` in .NET:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ftp = WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/softlib/MSLFILES/aspwebwiz2k.zip");
        //ftp.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("anonymous","anonymous");
        var response=ftp.GetResponse();
        var stream=response.GetResponseStream();
        var ms = ToMemoryStream(stream);

        var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
        var entry=archive.GetEntry("file name here");

        var doc=XDocument.Load(entry.Open());
    }

    public static MemoryStream ToMemoryStream( Stream stream)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var buffer = new byte[4096];

        while (true)
        {
            var readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (readCount == 0)
                break;

            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

Comment: Plus one for the great efforts, the other answer helped me. but your answer is great too. i wish i could accept more than one answer.